# Find how many friends were chatting

Tags: combinatorics

Some friends were corresponding by e-mail. Each sent email was received by all other friends, except for the person who sent the email. It is known that each 1 person wrote 10 emails, resulting in a total of 200 emails received by all friends. Calculate the number of friends.

I tried this in 2 ways and got different answers.

1st: I divided 200 by 20. That's how many people sent emails but did not receive them. Then I subtracted 20 from 200 and got 180 people.

2nd: Each friend sent an email (this is the case for 1 email), all of the friends have received it except for him. If the group consists of $n$ people, $n-1$ people received 1 letter after sending the first letter. Then each friend repeated the actions. So, in the case of a random $n$, we get $n$ people who sent $n-1$ people a letter. Total emails $n(n-1)$ in case of sending one email.
And now this operation was repeated $10$ times. That is, the total number of letters is $10n(n-1)$.
There are 200 emails,so $10n(n-1)=200$. $n=5$ and $n=-4$. The answer can't be negative, so it is 5.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! What have you tried, and what question do *you* have about the problem?

Comment: What have you tried? Please read how to ask a good question https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question. Calculate the amount of friends is not correct usage of _amount_. I am guessing this is translation from another language.

Comment: Hello, I tried this problem like this:
A total of 200 emails were received, each sent 10, except for himself. If we divide 200/10, we get 20: this is how many people sent emails, but did not receive them.Then I just subtracted 20 from 200 and got 180.
So I think that I did not get the right answer and I would like to know what's wrong in my solving.

Comment: I can edit my question and write there what I've tried to do to solve

Comment: I definitely agree with the second approach, that's exactly how I would've done it. I don't quite follow the logic for the first approach though, do you think you could go into more detail about your thought process?

Comment: I concur. The second solution is the correct one (it’s easy to see it works - 10*5 emails received by 4 people = 200.